# Exponential family: examples where scaling constant is data dependent

Tags: normalization, exponential-family

The general form of a exponential family distribution is given as

$$p(x|\theta) = h(x) g(\theta) \exp(\theta^Tu(x))$$

where $h(x)$ is referred to as the "scaling constant" (e.g. in Murphy's ML book).

All the examples that I encountered so far (Bernoulli, Multinomial, Normal) actually don't use $x$ as an argument (so it is indeed a constant there).

Which are prototypical examples where $x$ is actually used to compute that value (i.e. where $h$ is indeed a function of $x$)?
Is "scaling constant" the typical name to refer to $h(x)$?

Comment: I do not understand why he calls it "scaling constant" given that it depends on $x$. Does he mean maybe that it is a constant with respect to $\theta$ in the likelihood?

Comment: I have never heard $h(x)$ being referred as scaling constant. This function is associated with the dominating measure and hence changes when one changes the dominating measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual name is "carrier measure".   You can find that in papers by Nielsen and Shao's textbook off the top of my head.  Sometimes the carrier measure is inside the exponentiation.

The carrier measure of a continuous exponential family can always be made unity by stretching the support: Expand places where it would otherwise be more than one; contract places where it would be less than one.  This is probably why most of the continuous exponential families we commonly use are defined so that the carrier measure disappears: E.g., Gaussian, gamma, beta, inverse-gamma.  We then derive distributions with transformed supports like log-normal and beta-prime that often have non-unity carrier measure.

The carrier measure of a discrete exponential family typically doesn't have this luxury since you can't split the outcomes.  For example, the Poisson distribution has carrier measure $\frac1{x!}$; it's not like you can break outcomes into tiny pieces.

Comment: Even with discrete domains, the choice of $h$ is arbitrary: when defining the Poisson distribution, switching from the counting measure $\lambda(k)=1$ to the measure $\lambda(k)=1/k!$ leads to $h(k)=1$.